# Torque of disk about a point when there is a force acting on the disk surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

As the picture shows, the force **F** acts on the solid disk at the contact point $t$. In this case, how do we calculate the net torque about the point $O$, mainly the contribution of **F** to the net torque.

[image]

**Parameters**:
r: disk radius, 
angle $\angle$Oct = $\theta$, 
**G**: disk gravity, 
**F** = ($F_x, F_y$), 
coordinate of disk center $c$ relative to $O$: ($x_c, y_c$).

PS: The beam $Ob$ and the disk are considered as a rigid body.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk accelerates as if all the forces acting on it are acting upon the center of mass. Thus, if the disk is free to move on a frictionless surface, it will still obey the equation $$\vec F = m\vec a$$ Again, if the disk is free to move (not constrained to rotate about a certain axis, and no other force acting on it), it will always rotate about its center of mass. That is, if the force is applied at a distance $r$ from the center, we have the standard formula for torque: $$Fr \sin \theta = I\alpha$$ where $I = \frac{1}{2}mR^2$ is the [moment of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) about the center of mass, and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration.

The translational motion and the rotational motion can be separated. Imagine the disk as a point mass (that is, a dot) accelerating with $\vec F = m\vec a$, and rotating about it. **The equation for net torque doesn't change just because the disk itself is accelerating.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83209/discussion-on-answer-by-user7777777-torque-of-disk-about-a-point-when-there-is-a).